# I Have set my ENV Variables and PhoneGap Android Build still fails

Tags: android, cordova, ant, build

Hi i have problem with building android application,
i downloaded phonegap and cordowa (npm install), then set env vars:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/marek/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/marek/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/marek/Android/Sdk/build-tools

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant
ANDROID_HOME=/home/marek/Android/Sdk
```

And still getting this error:

```
/home/marek/PhoneGapProjects/test-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126

                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/marek/PhoneGapProjects/test-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/marek/PhoneGapProjects/test-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/marek/PhoneGapProjects/test-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: /home/marek/PhoneGapProjects/test-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

It would be really great if someone could help me.

Comment: P.S. - I'am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you running the build?

Try `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" phonegap build android`

Comment: I was simpy executing phonegap build android, but tried this way, still the same

Comment: and if you `echo $ANDROID_HOME` you see the correct path?

Comment: marek@marek-Lenovo-G580:~/PhoneGapProjects/test-app/platforms$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/marek/Android/Sdk

yes correct

Comment: Yeah Phonegap's errors are pretty bad. So it is set. What if you tried using `export` to set it in `~/.bashrc` rather than just assigning? Does that change anything?

Comment: Thank's for answer, i have found solution. I run build with --info mod, and it was caused by Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library, fixed my config files and it worked

Comment: @Mark That error only showed up when you ran with `--info`?

Comment: yes,  without - - info i saw only stack from first post

Comment: Well glad you got it resolved. That's pretty strange though. I've had that issue before but didn't need to run `build` with any special flag.

Comment: Thank you for help, and it seem strange for me too that i cant see error that causes fail of building